# Average of List from input file

Tags: c#, list, average

I have an input file where I have primary scores and secondary scores. I need to find the average of the primary scores.

I am able to read the primary and secondary score and add them into Lists. But while calculating average, I am getting an error on the line **s1.Average(PrimaryScore);**

I am attaching the program.cs and regression .cs classes. Thank you for any help.

```
class Program
{
    static Regression s1;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int numRecords = 0;
        List<double> PrimaryScore = new List<double>();
        List<double> SecondaryScore = new List<double>();
        FileStream fs = null;
        Console.Write("Enter the file path: ");

        while (fs == null)
        {
            string fileName = Console.ReadLine();
            fs = OpenFileForRead(fileName);
        }

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
        ReadFirstValueAsInt(sr, ref numRecords);
        sr.ReadLine();    
        for (int i = 1; i <= numRecords; i++)
        {
            ReadRecordAsDoubleList(sr, PrimaryScore);
            ReadRecordAsDoubleList(sr, SecondaryScore);

            Console.WriteLine("Primary Data set {0}: ", i);
            foreach (double d in PrimaryScore)
                Console.Write(d + " ");

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
            PrimaryScore.Clear();
            sr.ReadLine(); 
            Console.WriteLine("Secondary Data set {0}: ", i);
            foreach (double d in SecondaryScore)
                Console.Write(d + " ");

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
            SecondaryScore.Clear();
        }
        s1 = new Regression();
        s1.Average(PrimaryScore); //getting an error here
    }

    public static FileStream OpenFileForRead(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            return new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write("Problem opening file {0}, please enter a valid path: ", fileName);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void ReadFirstValueAsInt(StreamReader sr, ref int numRecords)
    {
        try
        {
            numRecords = Int32.Parse(sr.ReadLine());

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.Message);
        }
    }

    public static void ReadRecordAsDoubleList(StreamReader sr, List<double> cr)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] doubles = sr.ReadLine().Split(new char[] { ' ' });

            foreach (string s in doubles)
                cr.Add(Double.Parse(s));

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Regression Class which is called from the program Class

```
class Regression
{

    public static double Average(List<double> PrimaryScore)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        foreach (int element in PrimaryScore)
            sum += element;

        return (double)sum / PrimaryScore.Count;
    }
}
```

Comment: 'I am getting an error on the line' --- compile error or run-time exception?

Comment: What is the error message

Comment: As a side note: you should close `Stream`s after using them or wrap them in a `using` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Average` is declared as a static method, so you eithr call it using `Regression.Average(PrimaryScore)` or, you remove the `static` modifier from the method definition so you could keep calling it using `s1.Average(PrimaryScore)`.

such as your method defintion becomes like this :

```
 public static double Average(List PrimaryScore)
 {
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. 
How do I display the average?

Comment: @KinjalMaruShah display the average as in print it on the console window ? `Console.WrtieLine(s1.Average(PrimaryScore))` ?